# Why picturesArray is always empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
var request = require("request").defaults({ encoding: null });

var picturesArray = [];
request.get('http://www.vorohome.com//images/assets/159314_887955.png', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        data = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
        console.log(data)
        picturesArray[0] = data;
    }
});
console.log(picturesArray);
```

Comment: @Armin — That's terrible advice. There's a callback function will fill fire when the data is available. Guessing how long it will take to become available is just stupid.

Comment: But guys any suggestion how I can collect the data in pictureArray?

Comment: See the duplicate question linked in the big yellow box at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling

```
console.log(picturesArray);
```

before asynchronous action is finished.

If you'll add this log inside the request callback - you'll get the proper result.

Comment: Yes, he could put timeout to resolve

Comment: @Armin — No! Absolutely not! Guessing how long an asynchronous function will take to resolve is stupid. Just use the callback feature which that function provides to tell you when it is done.

Comment: Thanks @hsz, but how can I get the response in array?

Comment: @Kunal Read linked question.

Comment: @quentin aa, i get it now, thanks